# How to properly use the new review queues?

Tags: discussion, support, reviewing

The new *first answer* and *first question* queues let you do these actions:

[image]

I've encountered a couple of posts that were a spam question and a question posted as an answer. The actions suggested were not useful to me:

- They didn't clearly **look OK**
- There was no reason to **edit** them
- The default **feedbacks** only give suggestions on how to improve questions/answers to new users

If I leave a custom comment and/or flag the post nothing is registered as an actual action made by the reviwer. So, how should I manage these situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, the current way to use these queues is to either leave feedback using the canned comments, (which get written on the post by the [Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user), mark the post as "Looks Ok", or edit the post in question. You can also perform an "Other Action" (see below) to also finish the review item.  <s>You can flag the post if it needs it, but currently this will not allow you to complete the review task, leaving you in a weird position of having to still either leave feedback using the canned comments, or mark it as ok/edit it - all of which seem awkward to do after flagging the post.</s>

---

There are a lot of improvements planned for these new queues, as discussed on the [SE Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release). There is a [helpful answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369148#369148) of all the implemented/planned/rejected bug fixes and feature requests for the new queues on the post.  I encourage you to check it out, as it is quite a lot to repeat here.

<s>The biggest issue (in my opinion) that is currently being planned can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369036#369036) - this deals with the flagging awkwardness I mentioned earlier.</s>

#### Update:

Looks like the options now are the following:

[image]

The main change being the "Other Action" option, which will automatically be selected if you:

- Flag the post
- Vote to close (questions only)
- Comment on the post
- Upvote on an existing comment
- Vote on the post

Comment: One thing I noticed (and its on the [SE Meta post as a request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369018/342074)) is the canned comments don't quite make sense for all sites.  For example, the one canned comment asks the OP to provide a working solution with code, which doesn't really apply to our site.